# Create reports programatically with apex?

Tags: apex, api, reporting, analytics

[Winter 14' gives the ability to run and get report data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/337/can-report-data-be-accessed-programatically), but I can't find anything about creating reports dynamically in the API documentation - http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_analytics/index.htm

I am writing unit tests for some reporting functionality and I can't rely on one client having the same reports as another, so I need to mock some reports. I found [this answer about making report folders programatically](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/32843/can-we-create-report-folders-through-apex), but nothing about reports. Is there a way to create reports via apex?

EDIT - after search a lot more, I found that you [can't create a report from SOQL](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrVcAAK&sort=2).

However, I did find some guidance from Salesforce about [how to test reports in the Reporting API.](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_analytics_test_reports.htm)

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a report programmatically from a unit test.  You might be able to do it with the [Apex Wrapper Salesforce Metadata API](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) from outside of a unit test context, though.

I'm not sure of the design of your program, but maybe you can abstract away the report to a data source interface  and mock that in your unit tests.  E.g.,

```
public class MyReportService {
    DataSource source;
    public MyReportService(DataSource ds) {
        this.source = ds;
    }

   // Bunch of other methods that do things with with data source.
}
```

Then in your unit test:

```
DataSource myMockDataSource = generateMyMockDataSourceSomehow();
MyReportService service = new MyReportService(myMockDataSource);

Test.startTest();
Integer retVal = service.answerMagicalQuestion();
Test.stopTest();

System.assertEquals(42, retVal, 'magical answer wrong');
```